# Selecting multiple things at once with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following layout for my database:

[image]

I'm trying to return a massive object containing all threads a user is in, *and all users in each of those threads*.

The `thread_participants` table is a many-to-many table for keeping track of which users are in which threads.  The user can "join" or "leave" threads as they choose - this is not a thread in the sense of a forum.

I have managed to get all threads the user is in selected, but doing the reverse lookup and getting all users in that thread is beyond me.  So far my code (which only selects threads given a user_id) is this:

```
SELECT id,title,creation_date FROM `threads`
WHERE id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM `thread_participants` WHERE user_id = ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second instance of `thread_participants` and join it to  `threads`, and then join to the `users` table:

```
   SELECT t.id, t.title, t.creation_date, u.nickname, u.email
      FROM `threads` t
           JOIN `thread_participants` p
                ON t.id = p.thread_id
           JOIN `users` u
                ON p.user_id = u.id
     WHERE t.id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM `thread_participants` WHERE user_id = ?)
```